# sort register with knpPaginator in symfony2.8

Tags: symfony-2.8, knppaginator

I'm learning Symfony Framework (version2.8). I'm working with knpPaginator, to show all users from my database. Now I'm trying to sort register, but I can't.
This is an image of my project until now
[Users View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfBqL.png)

When I click on name(Nombre) filter, this error appears
There is no component aliased by [u] in the given Query

Please your help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Configuration:

```
knp_paginator:
    page_range: 5                      # default page range used in pagination control
    default_options:
        page_name: page                # page query parameter name
        sort_field_name: sort          # sort field query parameter name
        sort_direction_name: direction # sort direction query parameter name
        distinct: true                 # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
template:
    pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sliding.html.twig     # sliding pagination controls template
    sortable: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig # sort link template
```

Controller:

```
public function listAction(Request $request)
{
    $em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $dql   = "SELECT a FROM AcmeMainBundle:Article a";
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql);

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query, /* query NOT result */
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
    10/*limit per page*/
);

// parameters to template
return $this->render('AcmeMainBundle:Article:list.html.twig', array('pagination' => $pagination));
```

}

View:

```
{# total items count #}
<div class="count">
    {{ pagination.getTotalItemCount }}
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
    {# sorting of properties based on query components #}
        <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Id', 'a.id') }}</th>
        <th{% if pagination.isSorted('a.Title') %} class="sorted"{% endif %}>       {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Title', 'a.title') }}</th>
        <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Release', ['a.date', 'a.time']) }}</th>
    </tr>

{# table body #}
{% for article in pagination %}
<tr {% if loop.index is odd %}class="color"{% endif %}>
    <td>{{ article.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ article.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ article.date | date('Y-m-d') }}, {{ article.time |     date('H:i:s') }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{# display navigation #}
<div class="navigation">
     {{ knp_pagination_render(pagination) }}
</div>
```

More details:
https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle

Comment: Thaks @habibun for your answer, but my issue isn't resolve yet.

Comment: @FranciscoMorales you can send your code for better understand your issue.

Comment: Hi @habibun, below this message is my code. Thanks for your help

Comment: consider index action(this works in my project): https://github.com/habibun/craft/blob/master/src/Acme/SetupBundle/Controller/SupplierController.php

Answer (score 0):

This is my Code:

**Config.yml**

```
# KnpPaginatorBundle
knp_paginator:
    page_range: 5                      # default page range used in pagination control
    default_options:
        page_name: page                # page query parameter name
        sort_field_name: sort          # sort field query parameter name
        sort_direction_name: direction # sort direction query parameter name
        distinct: true                 # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
    template:
        pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig     # sliding pagination controls template
        sortable: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig # sort link template
```

My **UserController**

```
<?php

namespace SRQ\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use SRQ\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use SRQ\UserBundle\Form\UserType;




class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $searchQuery = $request->get('query');

        if(!empty($searchQuery))
        {
            $finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.app.user');
            $users = $finder->createPaginatorAdapter($searchQuery);
        }
        else
        {
            $fm = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $dql = "SELECT u FROM SRQUserBundle:User u ORDER BY u.id DESC";
            $users = $fm->createQuery($dql); 
        }

            $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
            $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $users, $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
            5
        );


        $deleteFormAjax = $this->createCustomForm(':USER_ID', 'DELETE', 'srq_user_delete');



        return $this->render('SRQUserBundle:User:index.html.twig', array('pagination' => $pagination,
        'delete_form_ajax' => $deleteFormAjax->createView()));

    }

    public function addAction()
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($user);

        return $this->render('SRQUserBundle:User:add.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));

    }


    private function createCreateForm(User $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('srq_user_create'),
            'method' => 'POST'
            ));

        return $form;
    }

    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isValid())
        {
            $password = $form->get('password')->getData();

            $passwordConstraint = new Assert\NotBlank();
            $errorList = $this->get('validator')->validate($password, $passwordConstraint);

            if(count($errorList) == 0)
            {
                $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
                $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $password);

                $user->setPassword($encoded);

                $fm = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $fm->persist($user);
                $fm->flush();

                $successMessage = $this->get('translator')->trans('The user has been created.');
                $this->addFlash('mensaje', $successMessage);

                return $this->redirectToRoute('srq_user_index');
            }
            else
            {
                $errorMessage = new FormError($errorList[0]->getMessage());
                $form->get('password')->addError($errorMessage);   
            }
        }

        return $this->render('SRQUserBundle:User:add.html.twig', array('form' =>$form->createView()));

    }

    public function editAction($id)
    {
        $fm = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $fm->getRepository('SRQUserBundle:User')->find($id);

        if(!$user)    
        {
            $messageException = $this->get('translator')->trans('User not found.');
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('$messageException');
        }

        $form = $this->createEditForm($user);

        return $this->render('SRQUserBundle:User:edit.html.twig', array('user' => $user, 'form' => $form->createView()));

    }

    private function createEditForm(User $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $entity, array('action' => $this->generateUrl('srq_user_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())), 'method' => 'PUT'));

        return $form;
    }

    public function updateAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        $fm = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $user = $fm->getRepository('SRQUserBundle:User')->find($id);

        if(!$user)    
        {
            $messageException = $this->get('translator')->trans('User not found.');
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('$messageException');
        }

        $form = $this->createEditForm($user);
        $form ->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $password = $form->get('password')->getData();
            if(!empty($password))
            {
                $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
                $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $password);
                $user->setPassword($encoded);
            }
            else
            {
                $recoverPass = $this->recoverPass($id);
                $user->setPassword($recoverPass[0]['password']);
            }

            if($form->get('role')->getData() == 'ROLE_ADMIN')
            {
                $user->setIsActive(1);
            }

            $fm->flush();

            $successMessage = $this->get('translator')->trans('The user has been modified.');
            $this->addFlash('mensaje', $successMessage);
            return $this->redirectToRoute('srq_user_edit', array('id' => $user->getId()));
        }
        return $this->render('SRQUserBundle:User:edit.html.twig', array('user' => $user, 'form' => $form->createView()));
    }

    private function recoverPass($id)
    {
        $fm = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $fm->createQuery(
            'SELECT u.password
            FROM SRQUserBundle:User u
            WHERE u.id = :id'
            )->setParameter('id', $id);

            $currentPass = $query->getResult();
            return $currentPass;
    }


    public function viewAction($id)
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SRQUserBundle:User');

        $user = $repository->find($id);

        if(!$user)    
        {
            $messageException = $this->get('translator')->trans('User not found.');
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('$messageException');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createCustomForm($user->getId(), 'DELETE', 'srq_user_delete');

        return $this->render('SRQUserBundle:User:view.html.twig', array('user' => $user, 'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView()));
    }

    private function createDeleteForm($user)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('srq_user_delete', array('id' => $user->getId())))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->getForm();

    }

    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $fm = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $user = $fm->getRepository('SRQUserBundle:User')->find($id);

        if(!$user)    
        {
            $messageException = $this->get('translator')->trans('User not found.');
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('$messageException');
        }


        $allUsers = $fm->getRepository('SRQUserBundle:User')->findAll();
        $countUsers = count($allUsers);

        $form = $this->createCustomForm($user->getId(), 'DELETE', 'srq_user_delete');
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            if($request->isXMLHttpRequest())
            {
                $res = $this->deleteUser($user->getRole(), $fm, $user);

                return new Response(
                    json_encode(array('removed' => $res['removed'], 'message' => $res['message'], 'countUsers' => $countUsers)),
                    200,
                    array('Content-Type' => 'application/json')
                    );
            }

            $res = $this->deleteUser($user->getRole(), $fm, $user);

            $this->addFlash($res['alert'], $res['message']);
            return $this->redirectToRoute('srq_user_index');
        }

    }


    private function deleteUser($role, $fm, $user)
    {
        if($role == 'ROLE_USER')
        {
            $fm->remove($user);
            $fm->flush();

            $message = $this->get('translator')->trans('The user has been deleted.');
            $removed = 1;
            $alert = 'mensaje';
        }
        elseif($role == 'ROLE_ADMIN')
        {
            $message = $this->get('translator')->trans('The user could not be deleted.');
            $removed = 0;
            $alert = 'error';
        }

        return array('removed' => $removed, 'message' => $message, 'alert' => $alert);
    }

    private function createCustomForm($id, $method, $route)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
               ->setAction($this->generateUrl($route, array('id' => $id)))
               ->setMethod($method)
               ->getForm();
    }

}
```

My Views/User/index.html.twig

```
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ parent() }}

    {# Progress bar #}
    <div class="progress no-border hidden" id="delete-progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
    </div>


    {{ include('SRQUserBundle:User:messages/success.html.twig') }}
    {{ include('SRQUserBundle:User:messages/danger.html.twig') }}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="page-header margin-none">
                <h2 class="padding-none">{% trans %} Users {% endtrans %}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                {% trans %} Total records: {% endtrans %} <span id="total">{{ pagination.getTotalItemCount }}</span> 
                <p>
                <form method="get" action="" class="form-inline" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="query" value="{{ app.request.get('query') }}" class="form-control" placeholder="{{'Search user'|trans}}" required />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="{{ 'Search'|trans }}" class="btn btn-default">
                </form>
                {% if not pagination|length %}
                    <h2>{{ 'No search results'|trans}}</h2>
                {% endif %}

                {% if pagination|length %}

                <br>
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th> {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Username'|trans, 'u
                                .username') }}</th>

                            <th{% if pagination.isSorted('u.firstName') %} class="sorted"{% endif %}>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'First name'|trans, 'u
                                .firstName') }}</th>
                            <th> {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Last name'|trans, 'u
                                .lastName') }} </th>
                            <th> {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Email'|trans, 'u
                                .email') }} </th>
                            <th> {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Role'|trans, 'u
                                .role') }} </th>
                            <th> {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Created'|trans, 'u
                                .createdAt') }} </th>
                            <th> {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Updated'|trans, 'u
                                .updatedAt') }} </th>
                            <th>{{ 'Actions'| trans}}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for user in pagination %}
                            <tr data-id="{{ user.id }}">
                                <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    {% if user.role == 'ROLE_ADMIN' %}
                                        <strong>
                                            {% trans %} Administrator {% endtrans %}
                                        </strong>
                                    {% elseif user.role == 'ROLE_USER' %}
                                        <strong>
                                            {% trans %} User {% endtrans %}
                                        </strong>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </td>
                                <td>{{ user.createdAt|date('d-m-Y H:i') }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.updatedAt|date('d-m-Y H:i') }}</td>
                                <td class="actions">
                                    <a href="{{ path('srq_user_view', { id: user.id }) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
                                        {{ 'View'|trans }}
                                    </a>

                                    <a href="{{ path('srq_user_edit', { id: user.id }) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                                        {{ 'Edit'|trans }}
                                    </a>

                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-delete">
                                        {{ 'Delete'|trans }}
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                {% endif %}
                {# Display navigation #}
                <div class="navigation">
                    {{ knp_pagination_render(pagination) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


{{ include('SRQUserBundle:User:forms/form.html.twig', { form: delete_form_ajax, message: 'Are you sure ?'|trans, id: 'form-delete', with_submit: false}) }}

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/srquser/js/delete-user.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Sorting by name
[Sort_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5LJ5.png)

Error message:

```
There is no component aliased by [u
] in the given Query

500 Internal Server Error - UnexpectedValueException

Stack Trace

in vendor/knplabs/knp-components/src/Knp/Component/Pager/Event/Subscriber/Sortable/Doctrine/ORM/Query/OrderByWalker.php at line 54   -
            $alias = $aliases[$index];
            if ($alias !== false) {
                if (!array_key_exists($alias, $components)) {
                    throw new \UnexpectedValueException("There is no component aliased by [{$alias}] in the given Query");
                }
                $meta = $components[$alias];
                if (!$meta['metadata']->hasField($field)) {
at OrderByWalker ->walkSelectStatement (object(SelectStatement)) 
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/TreeWalkerChain.php at line 112   +
at TreeWalkerChain ->walkSelectStatement (object(SelectStatement)) 
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php at line 380   +
at Parser ->parse () 
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Pagination/Paginator.php at line 260   +
at Paginator ->getCountQuery () 
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Pagination/Paginator.php at line 123   +
at Paginator ->count ()
at count (object(Paginator)) 
in vendor/knplabs/knp-components/src/Knp/Component/Pager/Event/Subscriber/Paginate/Doctrine/ORM/QuerySubscriber/UsesPaginator.php at line 47   +
at UsesPaginator ->items (object(ItemsEvent), 'knp_pager.items', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
at call_user_func (array(object(UsesPaginator), 'items'), object(ItemsEvent), 'knp_pager.items', object(TraceableEventDispatcher)) 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php at line 61   +
at WrappedListener ->__invoke (object(ItemsEvent), 'knp_pager.items', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
at call_user_func (object(WrappedListener), object(ItemsEvent), 'knp_pager.items', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher)) 
in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 1858   +
at EventDispatcher ->doDispatch (array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'knp_pager.items', object(ItemsEvent)) 
in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 1773   +
at EventDispatcher ->dispatch ('knp_pager.items', object(ItemsEvent)) 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php at line 140   +
at TraceableEventDispatcher ->dispatch ('knp_pager.items', object(ItemsEvent)) 
in vendor/knplabs/knp-components/src/Knp/Component/Pager/Paginator.php at line 113   +
at Paginator ->paginate (object(Query), '1', '5') 
in src/SRQ/UserBundle/Controller/UserController.php at line 38   +
at UserController ->indexAction (object(Request))
at call_user_func_array (array(object(UserController), 'indexAction'), array(object(Request))) 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php at line 144   +
at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1') 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php at line 64   +
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true) 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php at line 69   +
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true) 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php at line 185   +
at Kernel ->handle (object(Request)) 
in web/app_dev.php at line 32   +
Logs   -

1 error
INFO - Matched route "srq_user_index".
INFO - Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token.
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Subscriber\SlidingPaginationSubscriber::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "knp_pager.before" to listener "Knp\Component\Pager\Event\Subscriber\Sortable\SortableSubscriber::before".
DEBUG - Notified event "knp_pager.before" to listener "Knp\Component\Pager\Event\Subscriber\Filtration\FiltrationSubscriber::before".
DEBUG - Notified event "knp_pager.before" to listener "Knp\Component\Pager\Event\Subscriber\Paginate\PaginationSubscriber::before".
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception UnexpectedValueException: "There is no component aliased by [u ] in the given Query" at /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/knplabs/knp-components/src/Knp/Component/Pager/Event/Subscriber/Sortable/Doctrine/ORM/Query/OrderByWalker.php line 54
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Subscriber\SlidingPaginationSubscriber::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
Stack Trace (Plain Text)
```